# pl sql %NOTFOUND

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm just wondering why this piece of code is not working. I don't have any supplier `id=1` in my table.

```
DECLARE
    VAR SUPP_NM VARCHAR(100);
    VAR_SUPP_ID  NUMBER := 1;
    WHILE_VAR CHAR := 'Y';
BEGIN
    SELECT SUPP_NM
    INTO VAR_SUPP_NM
    FROM TEST.SUPPLIER
    WHERE SUPP_ID = VAR_SUPP_ID;
        
    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQL DATA NOT FOUND');
    ELSIF SQL%FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATA FOUND');
    END IF;    
END;
```

I get a 01403 error in Toad but not handled as `sql%notfound`.

Why isn't the `sql%notfound` working?

Comment: Please edit that information into your question. (And always say exactly what is happening/what error you're getting in the future directly in the question when you post it. It's really important.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To catch the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception rewrite your code as follows by adding `exception` section:

```
DECLARE
    VAR_SUPP_NM VARCHAR2(100);
    VAR_SUPP_ID  NUMBER := 1;
    WHILE_VAR CHAR := 'Y';
BEGIN
  SELECT SUPP_NM
    INTO VAR_SUPP_NM
    FROM TEST.SUPPLIER
   WHERE SUPP_ID = VAR_SUPP_ID;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATA FOUND');

exception
  when no_data_found 
  then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQL DATA NOT FOUND');

END;
```

Checking `SQL%FOUND` or `SQL%NOTFOUND` have no meaning in the case of `select into` statement, because if the select statement returns no rows it will always raise `no_data_found` exception, except, if that select statement invokes aggregate function, it will always return data or null if no rows has been selected.

Do not use `varchar` datatype, use `varchar2` datatype instead.

Answer (score 7):

Nicholas's answer is what you want if you want to use `SELECT INTO`. However, if it is more important that you are able to use `%FOUND` or `%NOTFOUND`, consider `FETCH`ing from a cursor instead:

```
DECLARE
    VAR SUPP_NM VARCHAR2(100);
    VAR_SUPP_ID  NUMBER := 1;
    WHILE_VAR CHAR := 'Y';
    CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT SUPP_NM
        FROM TEST.SUPPLIER
        WHERE SUPP_ID = VAR_SUPP_ID;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    FETCH c1 INTO VAR_SUPP_NM;

    IF c1%NOTFOUND THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQL DATA NOT FOUND');
    ELSIF c1%FOUND THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATA FOUND');
    END IF;

    CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

Nick's answer is correct.

In oracle documentation however it is stated that `SQL%NOTFOUND` works with `SELECT INTO`  but before one could check `SQL%NOTFOUND` to be TRUE an error is generated called as `no_data_found`.

so to use `SQL%NOTFOUND` one first needs to hande `no_data_found` error.

```
DECLARE
    VAR SUPP_NM VARCHAR(100);
    VAR_SUPP_ID  NUMBER := 1;
    WHILE_VAR CHAR := 'Y';
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT SUPP_NM
        INTO VAR_SUPP_NM
        FROM TEST.SUPPLIER
        WHERE SUPP_ID = VAR_SUPP_ID;

        EXCEPTION 
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                null; -- or write something here if u want.
    END;
    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQL DATA NOT FOUND');
    ELSIF SQL%FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATA FOUND');
    END IF;    
END;
```

So what I have done is added a inner `BEGIN-END` block enclosing the `SELECT` statement that generates `no_data_found` exception. After that you can check for the value of `SQL%NOTFOUND`.

You can read more about this in oracle docs.
Start from this active link in mytime : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm#LNPLS00703